# background-size: cover; doesn't actually stretch the image?

Tags: html, css, background-image, positioning

Hey I think i'm doing something wrong because everyone says you can stretch an image using:

```
background-size: cover;
```

But when I use it, one or two sides are always getting cropped. I actually want a way to distort the image so it stretches to fit any screen responsively. Is that possible? Here is the exact code i've tried (i've tried a lot of variations of this):

```
.carnival {
    background: url(../images/carnival.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

html:

```
    <div class="carnival"></div>
```

Also for some reason if I remove any of the below the background doesn't show up at all:

```
height: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Can't believe how complicated setting a background image is for me.

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images ♦ Also for the second question, It's the expected behavior. The elements is positioned absolutely and does not have any content, therefore you should somehow specify the dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `background-size: 100% 100%;` instead of `cover`.

`cover` will cause the background image to be scaled so that it fills the block dimensions,
cropping any excess width or height depending on the miss-match between the aspect ratio of
the background image and the block to which the image is applied.

```css
body {
    margin:0;
}
.carnival {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/700/1400) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="carnival"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this worked, thanks a lot, this was no where, everyone just kept saying cover.

Comment: @MaryMelody Thank you for the fiddle, which I added to the answer (switched the image for dramatic effect).  All the best!